# Outlook Integration with Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.dll

Tags: visual-studio

We are using the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.dll to create Mails from within our ERP Software and send it through the local outlook client. We are using VisualStudio2019.

There are several options we are/were using (open mail window, add Address, CC, BCC, add subject and for example pdf files (like invoices or so)).

With a MS Update (Customer uses Outlook Prod: MS 365 Apps for EnterpriseApps) from October/November this funcionality is not working anymore. The call from withinour Application does not find the Outlook Client anymore.

Does anybod know if tht .DLL is still supported for Office2019/O365 Apps. If not is there any workarround or do we have to use the EWS Functionalty in the future

Thanks for your support.
Beat Mathys